# Iterate over two arrays simultaneously in List

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

How can I iterate two array in a list:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let colors = ["red", "green", "blue"]        
    let names = ["John", "Apple", "Seed"] 

    var body: some View {           
        VStack {
            List(colors, id: \.self) { color in
                Text(color)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For example I need to have: 
`Text("\(color) - \(animal)")`

My code would be like this (I know it's wrong but that's the idea):

```
    List(colors, animals id: \.self) { color, animal in
        Text("\(color) - \(animal)")
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

A bit simpler

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        List(Array(zip(colors, names)), id: \.self.0) { (color, name) in
            Text("\(color) - \(name)")
        }
    }
}
```

**Update: added variant for non-equal-size arrays**

This one of course is a bit complicated, but might be helpful

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        ListOfPairs()
    }
}

private func ListOfPairs() -> some View {
    var iter = names.makeIterator()
    let container = colors.reduce(into: Array<(String,String)>()) { (result, color) in
        result.append((color, iter.next() ?? "None" )) // << placeholder for empty
    }
    
    return List(container, id: \.self.0) { (color, name) in
        Text("\(color) - \(name)")
    }
}
```

Comment: If the `names` array has only two elements then it only shows me two results. How would it show me three (from array `colors`)

Answer (score 1):

You could make those two arrays into an object for each item, as they are related to each other. This can be made like so:

```
struct Object: Identifiable {
    let id: UUID = UUID()
    let color: String
    let name: String
}

let objects = [Object(color: "red", name: "John"),
               Object(color: "green", name: "Apple"),
               Object(color: "blue", name: "Seed")]
```

And used like so:

```
List(objects) { object in
    Text("\(object.color) - \(object.name)")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is all a bit cumbersome and creating types that don't need to be. For this reason SwiftUI has the ForEach Statement. The code can also look like this:

import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

```
let colors = ["red", "blue", "black", "purple", "green"]
let names = ["Paul", "Chris", "Rob", "Terry", "Andy"]

var body: some View {

    List {
        ForEach(0 ..< colors.count) {
            Text("Name \(self.names[$0]) has favorite color \(self.colors[$0]).")
        }
        .onDelete(perform: deleteRow)
    }
}
```

}

The result then looks like this:
[image]

Of course, both arrays need to have the same number of elements.

Answer (score 1):

Or, if you want to get two nice columns that you can manipulate the way you want it:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    let colors = ["red", "blue", "black", "purple", "green"]
    let names = ["Paul", "Chris", "Rob", "Terry", "Andy"]

    var body: some View {

        HStack {

            List(names, id: \.self) { name in
                Text(name)
            }
            .frame(width: 130)

            List(colors, id: \.self) { color in
                Text(color)
            }
            .frame(width: 160)
        }
    }
}
```

And then you get the result like this:
[image]